# Is saying "back to back" an AmE or BrE usage

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, phrasal-verbs

I have been often intrigued by the phrase "back-to-back".
Referring to "back" is reminiscent of the rear of the human body.

I usually hear-

- **back-to-back meetings**

Answer (score 1):

I see and use the phrase often as an American, and this cursory search of a UK news source shows it's common there too:

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/search/?queryText=back-to-back&sort=recent

It's common in both dialects and I've never thought of it as anatomical.

Comment: The usage originated in the US according to the Oxford Dictionary  but they also register in British English in examples such
as back-to-back semi-finals. (http://www.word-detective.com/2010/03/back-to-back/)

Comment: The phrase has always made me picture two people standing, er, back-to-back.

Comment: Me too @Hot Licks, which is why I deprecate the ungodly phrase *back-to-back-to-back*.

Answer (score 0):

> Americans certainly use back-to-back in reference to simple physical
>   arrangements such as **back-to-back seats** in a railway car.